# Magento2 Cart prices Multi Currency store

Tags: magento2, cart, currency

I have an online store with 3 different currencies. I fetch the prices of each product from an external web-service.

A weird thing is happening, when I switch the currency from the store, the prices of items that are already in the cart are not updated. How do I force this to be updated?

Thanks in advance you for your help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so i just figured this out

**in vendor\module\etc\events.xml**

```
<event name="sales_quote_item_set_product">
    <observer name="update_cart_prices_changed_currency" instance="vendor\module\Observer\CartPricesCurrencyChanged" />
</event>
```

**in vendor\module\Observer\CartPricesCurrencyChanged.php**

```
<?php

namespace vendor\module\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer as EventObserver;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;


class CartPricesCurrencyChanged implements ObserverInterface
{    
    public function execute(EventObserver $observer)
    {
        $price     = //Get your price here
        $quoteItem = $observer->getQuoteItem();
        $quoteItem->setOriginalCustomPrice($price);
        $quoteItem->getProduct()->setIsSuperMode(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: as this your answer please mark as such

Comment: done. Completly forgot to do that !